# Set HTML data width using php numeric string calculation?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to set the data width of my html progress bar using a php calculation.

Here's my code:

```
<li class="progress">
<?php $total = 100; ?>  
<?php $star = 4; ?>  
<?php $number = ($total / $star); ?>    
<div class="progress-bar" data-width="<?php echo $number; ?>">
</div>
</li>
```

Basically my $star string will hold any number between 1 and 5. This is exactly like a 5 star rating. Imagining my progress bar is broken into 5ths.

I want the progress bar data width to fill 20% at a time.

So if my star string contains number 1 this will fill the data width in my progress bar by 20%.

If my star string contains number 2 this will fill the data width in my progress bar by 40% etc until it gets to 100%.

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you describe what's "not working"?

Comment: If you're not going to answer to comments, then take it up with the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

php only does the "echo" of  something when has a request from the browser. So after  load the page, php will not update the data-width.
try to do that with some jquery and css.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, the line 

isn't taking into account that you want the progress bar to be broken into fifths. In your example, $number will equal 25.

That said, I think there is a more fundamental misunderstanding here. PHP is a server-side scripting language, which means that all of your PHP code will execute on the server before it gets sent to the client. This means that front-end things like animating progress bars won't even render until after after all the PHP has executed. Unless you are using this code in an AJAX callback, you will have a difficult time getting a progress bar to render using PHP. You'll really want JavaScript to handle the presentation of the progress bar display, but PHP can handle the data back-end.

Bootstrap has a nice progress bar that you can use if you want to go that route:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

I hope this helps and good luck!